# How can I receive a http request in Java/Python?

Tags: swift, http, request

I am quite new to HTTP requests, I am currently building an app which sends a question to a server, the server sends a response which the app receives and displays on the screen. This is the Swift code I use:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = encoded
        print("started request")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            // handle the result here
            
        }.resume()
```

I have already done a lot of research, but I just found code for sending an HTTP request from Java/Python, not receiving one. I am running my own PC at home which should work as a server, what code do I need in Python/Java to receive the request from Swift and respond to it?

Comment: https://djangostars.com/blog/rest-apis-django-development/

Comment: The response from your request should be in the `response` variable. You handle it in the part that says `// handle the resut here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that quickest way would be running spring boot app with @RestController class and @PostMapping method inside that will handle your request.

You'll need to create spring boot project with Spring Web dependency from https://start.spring.io/

Download it and add new file with controller class that will handle your rest requests.

Example controller:

```
@RestController
public class ExamplaryController {

@PostMapping(value = "api/users") 
public ResponseEntity<WhateverTypeYouWantToBeReturned> putDataExample(@RequestParam Integer page) {

    //code smth here

    return result;
    }
}
```